# Modelize multiple keywords in one field

Tags: elasticsearch, modeling

I have some products that I want to index in an elasticsearch system.
One of the field describing these products is the colour. For instance:

- Red
- Blue
- ...

Some of my products can have two or more colours.

Later on, I want to use facets (aggregation) on this field. And, if I understood correctly, you need to base facets on the type "keyword". So I was hoping to do something like that:

```
PUT products/product/1
{
  "name": "Trousers",
  "colour": "blue, brown",
}
```

But, as far as I can tell, what I'm doing here is creating a new keyword "blue, brown" instead of attaching two keywords to my product.

So, how do you input several keywords into one keyword field? Or should I use another approach?

Comment: Have you had success with my suggested approach of using an array?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill I did not have time to try it yet. I'll let you know for sure.

Comment: is my answer eligible for acceptance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: So, how do you input several keywords into one keyword field?
>
> A: I would store the values in an array that is of type keyword.

You would index your documents like so:

```
PUT products/product/1
{
  "name": "Trousers",
  "colour": ["blue", "brown"]
}
```